# Separate select for each collection element - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class workspace that contains a collection of sheets i.e. there is a one to many relationship between workspace and lists. A workspace may have a million lists. The problem is that when I access a single element of the sheets collection within a workspace all million of them are fetched. Is there a way for me to fetch these sheets in say sets of 10 or one by one?

Answer (score 0):

check out the [hibernate documentation on improving performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-custom).

Basically you want to use the `fetch` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

The key word is *extra-lazy* fetching.

Especially [this paragraph](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization) might be of interest. At the end it says:

> The createFilter() method is also used to efficiently retrieve subsets of a collection without needing to initialize the whole collection:
>
> > s.createFilter( lazyCollection, "").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(10).list();